# what if response variable is 'yes or no' in R?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, model-selection, multicollinearity

[image]

How to analyze above the data to predict the probability that people have disease with a model? Factors thought to influence infection include city, age, and diet.
BUT, I don't know how to do because the response variable is not numeric.
I tried to fit following model.

```
fm1 <- lm(disease ~ city, data=Data1)
fm2 <- lm(disease ~ age, data=Data1)
fm3 <- lm(disease ~ city + age + diet, data=Data1)
fm4 <- lm(disease ~ age + I(age^2) + city*diet, data=Data1)
```

but they couldn't be worked because the response variable is not numeric.

Comment: This only looks like an R question on the surface, it is really only deep conceptual misunderstandings.

Answer (score 11):

You'd normally use [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) for a situation like this (though there are a few alternatives).

You model $P(\text{response}=\tt{'yes'})$ in terms of the variables, but not as a linear function, like in ordinary regression.

Rather, if $p$ is $P(\text{response}=\tt{'yes'})$, then in logistic regression you model $\log(\frac{p}{1-p})$ as a linear function of the independent variables (predictors).

There are some good questions and answers about logistic regression here. You might start with [these questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logistic?sort=votes).

In R, you get a logistic regression via the `glm` command. It works a lot like the `lm` command, but it takes a `family` argument (in this case, `family=binomial` will give you logistic regression).

So instead of

```
fm1 <- lm(disease ~ city, data=Data1)
```

(where disease is a factor, not character*), you could have

```
fm1 <- glm(disease ~ city, data=Data1, family=binomial)
```

* though you can you can use functions like `factor` or `as.factor` to deal with that otherwise

Comment: but I need to select proper model for the data. I mean if I do a logistic regression via the glm, I could not get AIC. I don't know how to use the glm for getting the AIC.

Comment: AIC is computed automatically for GLMs; refer to the `glm` documentation.

Comment: The AIC is given right there in the output -- and the `AIC` function works on `glm` objects. [However, if you're doing model selection on the same data you're doing parameter estimation on, there will be some problems caused by that - bias in estimates, standard errors too small, and a number of other problems. This is discussed in a number of answers and comments here on CV.]

Comment: Thanks all. you are right. I have a problem with Residuals Sum Sq(RSS). To work the AIC function, I need to know the RSS but I don't know how to get the RSS. Could you let me know how to get the RSS using GLM?

Comment: The AIC for a logistic regression is *not* a function of RSS. The `AIC` function in R may be called directly on a `glm` object (`AIC(fm1)` in your case).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got AIC, but I still need the RSS. Because I need to create the AIC table in R, without relying on the AIC function. It is the reason why I ask the problem. Is there any solution?

Comment: Please read the first sentence of my previous comment again. I don't know how much plainer I can be about it, and there's no point in saying it twice. It's relatively easy to compute AIC for a GLM, so if that is what you want to do *ask a question about that instead*. Note that your original question (which I believe has been answered) makes no reference to AIC, nor to GLMs so it would be a new question.

Comment: Thanks again. so to solve the problem, should I change the models, like linear model? I could get the RSS in the linear model but I could use the model because of the response variable. Do you know how can deal with the problem? I need to create the AIC table in R without relying on the AIC. Moreover, I need to fit some models using various combinations and I decide which model is proper for the data.

Comment: I have no clear idea what you're saying there. The suggested GLM is a much more suitable model than any linear model. You can compute AIC for it - fairly easily - but NOT from RSS.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wonder how to use this formula by using R. ----->    AIC = -2*ln (likelihood)+2*K

Comment: The *easy* way to get the log likelihood would be to take the AIC returned by R and subtract 2K from it. Or you could try to write down the log-likelihood directly (since it sounds like this is work for some subject, you'd need to discuss how you'd do that, since we won't just [do your work for you](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)).