# Which statistical methods should I be using?

Tags: r, model

The data is about:
a binary variable as response; age; some binary categorical variables (0,1); some categorical variables which have more than 2 outcomes

The goal is to find which factors affect the response binary variable.

I intend to use logistic regression to fit this model, but I think more analyses are supposed to be applied.
I'm unfamiliar with handling categorical variables when the response variable is also a 0/1 variable. Could u give me some advice about this?

Thanks!  :)

Comment: This is not a programming question. If you need help choosing a statistical model, try [stats.se] which is intended for statistical questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255477/please-clarify-the-policy-on-homework-questions

Comment: Read the documentation on `glm` with `family=binomial`.

Comment: Some of the discussion in [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126996/what-if-response-variable-is-yes-or-no-in-r/126999#126999) may be of some use.

Answer (score 0):

Logistic regression seems like the most plausible approach. It can handle dichotomus, cathegorical and continous predictors.